# How can I use auth middleware's redirectTo method with url parameter and error message?

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, middleware, error-messaging

All I want to do is use a URL with a language parameter that results in the error message which I want to show the user. If I execute the commented code, I get the error;

> Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected.

On the other hand, if I execute my code that is not included in the comment, I get an error;

> Call to a member function with () on string.

I know the reasons for the mistakes. However, I am looking for a solution to achieve my goal.

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            // return \Redirect::route('login', app()->getLocale())->with('error', 'Error message');
            return route('login', ['locale' => app()->getLocale()])->with('error', 'Error message');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot chain `->with()` this can be chain by `redirect()->with()`

Comment: If you mean this code; `return redirect('login', ['locale' => app()->getLocale()])->with('error', 'Error message');` this resulted with error "Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type int, array given.."

Comment: @SüleymanŞentosun this way you are passing an parameter to login route .it'd result like /login/something . that's why it shouldn't be array.

Comment: `return redirect('login', app()->getLocale())->with('error', 'Error message');` It only wants integer type, but my parameter is string like 'en'.

Comment: @SüleymanŞentosun read this it will help. you https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call `with()` on the `route()` method, because the `route()` method only returns a string and is not in charge of a redirect.

If you would need to show an error message to the user after the `redirectTo()` method has been called, i think you can rather just keep the error message in Laravel `Session`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#interacting-with-the-session

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {

        // This next line keeps the error message in session for you to use on your redirect and then deletes it from session immediately after it has been used
        $request->session()->flash('error', 'Error message!');

        return route('login', ['locale' => app()->getLocale()]);
    }
}
```

You can now view the error message as you would normally:

In your controller:

```
$request->session()->get('error');
```

OR from your view:

```
{{ Session::get('error) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

try you cannot pass 2 parameter in `redirect()` it accept url not route name

```php
return redirect()->route('login', ['locale' => app()->getLocale()])->with('error', 'Error message');
```